# Exim + ClamAV file access error

Tags: exim

I have a working Exim setup and wanted to add AV scanning to that. I followd the instructions for setting up ClamAV [at this site](http://edin.no-ip.com/blog/hswong3i/exim4-clamav-spamassassin-greylistd-debian-etch-mini-howto). So now my permissions for the `/var/spool/exim` directory are as follows:

```
root@luxembourg:/var/spool/exim# ls -la
total 28
drwxrws---  6 exim exim 4096 2011-10-04 15:54 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 2011-09-30 13:45 ..
drwxrws---  2 exim exim 4096 2011-10-04 14:26 db
-rw-r--r--  1 root exim    6 2011-10-07 14:41 exim-daemon.pid
drwxrws--- 29 exim exim 4096 2011-10-07 14:33 input
drwxrws--- 24 exim exim 4096 2011-10-07 11:24 msglog
drwxrws---  2 exim exim 4096 2011-10-07 14:48 scan
```

Also, the clamav user is part of the exim group:

```
root@luxembourg:/var/spool/exim# grep clamav /etc/group
exim:x:1001:clamav
clamav:x:111:
```

Also, I have the following line in the clamd.conf file:

```
AllowSupplementaryGroups true
```

However, I get these errors:

```
2011-10-07 14:41:55 1RC9kR-0006mz-KD malware acl condition: clamd: ClamAV returned: /var/spool/exim/scan/1RC9kR-0006mz-KD/1RC9kR-0006mz-KD.eml: Can't open file or directory ERROR
2011-10-07 14:41:55 1RC9kR-0006mz-KD H=mail-vw0-f51.google.com [209.85.212.51] F=<someone@example.net> temporarily rejected after DATA
2011-10-07 14:42:45 1RC9lF-0006no-0Q malware acl condition: clamd: ClamAV returned: /var/spool/exim/scan/1RC9lF-0006no-0Q/1RC9lF-0006no-0Q.eml: Can't open file or directory ERROR
2011-10-07 14:42:45 1RC9lF-0006no-0Q H=mail-vw0-f51.google.com [209.85.212.51] F=<someone@example.net> temporarily rejected after DATA
2011-10-07 14:46:43 1RC9p5-0006nq-DV malware acl condition: clamd: ClamAV returned: /var/spool/exim/scan/1RC9p5-0006nq-DV/1RC9p5-0006nq-DV.eml: Can't open file or directory ERROR
2011-10-07 14:46:43 1RC9p5-0006nq-DV H=mail-vw0-f51.google.com [209.85.212.51] F=<someone@example.net> temporarily rejected after DATA
2011-10-07 14:48:20 1RC9qe-0006nt-0v malware acl condition: clamd: ClamAV returned: /var/spool/exim/scan/1RC9qe-0006nt-0v/1RC9qe-0006nt-0v.eml: Can't open file or directory ERROR
2011-10-07 14:48:20 1RC9qe-0006nt-0v H=mail-vw0-f51.google.com [209.85.212.51] F=<someone@example.net> temporarily rejected after DATA
2011-10-07 14:49:44 1RC9rz-0006o3-SP malware acl condition: clamd: ClamAV returned: /var/spool/exim/scan/1RC9rz-0006o3-SP/1RC9rz-0006o3-SP.eml: Can't open file or directory ERROR
2011-10-07 14:49:44 1RC9rz-0006o3-SP H=mail-vx0-f179.google.com [209.85.220.179] F=<someone@example.net> temporarily rejected after DATA
2011-10-07 14:51:04 1RC9tB-0006oF-Uf malware acl condition: clamd: ClamAV returned: /var/spool/exim/scan/1RC9tB-0006oF-Uf/1RC9tB-0006oF-Uf.eml: Can't open file or directory ERROR
2011-10-07 14:51:04 1RC9tB-0006oF-Uf H=localhost (mailserver.com) [127.0.0.1] F=<loclaluser@mailserver.com> temporarily rejected after DATA
```

I get these for ALL MAIL sent to my server and consequently, all mail is being "temporarily" rejected. This makes no sense to me, as the directory permissions are correct and `clamav` runs as the correct user.

I even tried running `clamav` with the `exim` user, but nothing changed (which is even more puzzling...).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem as you, it took me a while to figure out the root of the problem but eventually I have it up and running.

First; you have to edit the clamd apparmor profile in:

> /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.clamd

Since you installed from source, edit the following line:

`# For use with exim
  /var/spool/exim4/** r,`

to

`# For use with exim
  /var/spool/exim/** r,`

and then add this line:

`/var/spool/exim/scan/** rw,`

> sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart to reload the profiles.

I still got permission errors after doing this though and I read that exim and clamav user permissions don't always play nicely together. So I setup clamd.conf to be run as the same user and group as exim.

In my case,

> LocalSocketGroup yscheelen
>
> User yscheelen

After restarting clamav-daemon I managed to send the virus string through Telnet.

Clamav.log output:

> Sun Oct  9 22:27:16 2011 -> /var/spool/exim/scan/1RCzxo-0007tg-DW/1RCzxo-0007tg-DW.eml: Eicar-Test-Signature(75b94725bb947ffef38ede71495c5106:605) FOUND

Exim.log output:

> 2011-10-09 22:26:06 1RCzwh-0007tC-OE Completed
>   2011-10-09 22:27:16 1RCzxo-0007tg-DW H=localhost [127.0.0.1] F= rejected after DATA: This message contains a virus (Eicar-Test-Signature).

Good luck bro

Answer (score 1):

Just add the user used by clamav to the group used by exim. In the case of Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo adduser clamav Debian-exim
```

No need to edit the apparmor profile. And if you do so, I recommend editing /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.clamd instead.